# How to return the string value with double quotes in hstore?

Tags: postgresql, hstore

Create a sample table with a field with hstore data type:

```
CREATE TABLE books (
 attr hstore
 );
```

Insert values into table:

```
INSERT INTO books (attr)
VALUES
    (
       '"language"  => "English",
        "weight"   => "11.2 ounces"
        "page"=>"200"'
    );
```

Query the values of attr:

```
SELECT
    avals (attr)
FROM
    books;
```

In the output, why does "11.2 ounces" have double quote, while "English" has no quotes? Can we make "English" have double quotes too since it's a string?

```
{"11.2 ounces",English,200}
```

Can we generally return the string value with quotes and numeric value without quotes?

Comment: This is justs how Postgres represents the element in the array (because it contains a space, it is quoted). What is the actual problem that quotes are posing you?

Comment: I need to use the values in the output to generate a SQL query statement, in which char type should be quoted and numeric type should not. For example, update table set (language, page)=(val1, val2) where condition.
val1 should be quoted but val2 should not.